# Can I do 3 way SLI with 3 GTX 950?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, sli

I am thinking to connect my computer to 12 screen for work purposes. I searched about SLI/Crossfire.

I am wondering if I can make 3 way SLI with GTX 950. The purposes of it just to have multiple screen for viewing graph, programming code and so on all on different screen. Not for gaming or heavy computation.

Also for this, I am thinking to get between Pentium processor or core i3 with 4GB DDR4 RAM. I am taking this chance to also ask for anyone's thought about this build.

Thank you for your suggestion and help.

Comment: It doesn't sound like you need SLI to do what you want, a simple 3 graphics card setup should be fine.  Please avoid asking for shopping or hardware build recommendations as they are off-topic here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am sorry since this is my first time asking question here. You mention about `simple 3 graphics card setup`. Do you mean installing 3 graphics card in one rig without the need to SLI? Just plug it in each PCIE slot?

Comment: Exactly, SLI is for combining multiple graphics cards to power a single (or spread) game display so that they can combine processing power to render a scene.  They are perfectly able to work independently and drive their own displays and have multiple programs running across them without SLI.

Comment: @Ling - As Mokubai points you you might want to compare the CUDA computational performance of 3 independent GTX 950's compared to a 3-Way SLI configuration.  You don't need to use SLI to use multiple displays.  The current Nvidia drivers only support more then 2 cards in SLI inspecific configurations  I encourage you to determine what those configurations are before you make a decision.